# C strings: what could cause them to get mangled?

Tags: c, arrays, string, io

I have a function which takes a name and adds it to a list of names.  It returns a reference to the new name on that list:

```
#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH 24
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

static int numberofNames = 0;
static char** names = {NULL};

char* newName(const char* name) {
    /* copy characters up to max name length onto new name plus null term */
    char newName[MAX_NAME_LENGTH +1];
    memset(newName, '\0', MAX_NAME_LENGTH +1);
    memcpy(newName, name, MAX_NAME_LENGTH);

    /* add new name to list and return it */
    names = realloc(names, (numberOfNames) * sizeof(*names));
    assert(names);
    names[numberOfNames] = newName;

    /* test print, to be removed */
    printf("%s\n", names[numberOfNames]);

    return names[numberOfNames++];
}
```

and in my main function I have:

```
printf("%s\n", newName("Reginald VelJohnson"));
printf("%s\n", newName("Jaleel White"));
```

I expect the output:

```
Reginald VelJohnson
Reginald VelJohnson
Jaleel White
Jaleel White
```

But instead I get some random variant of:

```
Reginald VelJohnson
HvnaldJohn
Jaleel White
Hvel W
```

Running gdb I see that names[numberOfNames] seems to get mangled when ioputs.c is invoked after the function has returned and printf attempts to print the return value.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what could be going wrong here?

Comment: newName is allocated on the stack. That's not good. 

Worse, numberOfNames is zero in the first call to realloc(), causing UB when you assign values to the names array.

Also, the memcpy() reads outside its source argument since it uses MAX_NAME_LENGTH as count. 

A better algorithm would be to strdup(name) instead of copying it to newName.

Comment: I've used your suggestions to repair the code. It works now. If you'd like to offer this as an answer I'll accept it